# JUNIT runner Not able to identify the class name

Tags: java, junit, junit4

I am trying to execute a list of JUNIT test cases through JUNIT runner. The test case names are available in a excel sheet and I am retreiving the value one after the other.

I am not sure where I am going wrong. but my test runner is not executing. Could somebody help me on this.

```
Cell celltest = sheet.getCell(col,row);
String KeywordTest=celltest.getContents().concat(strClass);
//org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.runClasses(MyJUNITTestCase.class);
org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.runClasses(KeywordTest);
```

If I try the commented line, it is working fine. But if I try to retreive the values from an excel and store it to the "KeywordTest". The runclasses is not recognising it. Any idea where i went wrong.

Comment: What's the content of `KeywordTest` when it fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JUnitCore#runClasses](http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/javadoc/latest/org/junit/runner/JUnitCore.html#runClasses%28java.lang.Class...%29) takes a Class..., so you can't just pass a String to it like you're doing. You need to take the string "com.foo.bar.Foobar" and convert it into a class, as follows:

```
org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.runClasses(Class.forName(KeywordTest));
```

Please note that in java, variables usually start with a lower case letter, as follows:

```
Cell celltest = sheet.getCell(col,row);
String keywordTest=celltest.getContents().concat(strClass);
org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.runClasses(Class.forName(keywordTest));
```

And also, the keywordTest needs to be fully qualified. Foobar by itself won't work, you need com.foo.bar.Foobar.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am still getting the "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: POCWebDragDrop.class"

Comment: Is the class on the classpath etc?

Comment: Nope. Could you provide a code/syntax Where and how to use it please. I am working on add that similar package structure like "com.foo.bar.Foobar." to my script as well..but getting error message due to incorrect syntax

Comment: Hi, I moved the runner class file from a different package to the same package where i do have the test scripts. and I am getting the below error message. at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: I am still facing the same issue. Kindly let me know if you need any information?

Comment: The class needs to be on your classpath (look at the -cp option to java) and the class name needs to be fully qualified (com.xxx.yyy.POCWebDragDrop).